# Unable to change some files in RubyMine project

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine

Currently I'm having an issue where I cannot make any changes to some files in my project. When hitting the return or space bar key it will only select text and not create new lines or spaces respectively.

I'm fairly certain it has something to do with the VCS features but cannot seem to find any settings to correct the Read-Only issue I'm running into.

This issue did raise it head after installing the Dash plugin. Not sure if this is coincidental or related.

Thanks!

update: After further test it looks like some files go into a sort of preview mode. Return and Space bar keys will let you scan the file and hitting any other keys will wake up the edit function. Strange?

Comment: Most probably the issue is caused by extra plugins installed (for example, Haxe plugin is known for causing such issues). I'd suggest creating a support ticket, attaching your idea.log to it

Comment: Excellent suggestion.. I'm still using the 30 day trial and was hesitant to open a support ticket.  At this point I'm thinking of heading back to Sublime or VIM.

Comment: You shouldn't be a customer in order to submit a support ticket. And I can hardly provide other suggestions, as it's not clear what the problem is - and stackoverflow doesn't allow attaching files. But if you prefer to stick with Sublime - it's your choice

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to comment. I've opened a support ticket as you've suggested.

My apologies if you don't think my issue was clear. I didn't think it deserved a vote into the negative.

Answer (score 1):

IdealVim caused this for me. Definitely plugin related.